# How to delete a dictionary from a list based on values from another dictionary in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've spent about 6 hours on this, so I feel justified in asking a question. :)

My problem

```
list1 = [
       {extension: 1000, id: 1}
       {extension: 1001, id: 1}
       {extension: 1000, id: 2}
        ]

list2 = [
       {Stationextension: 1000, id: 1, name: bob}
       {Stationextension: 1001, id: 1, name: sal}
       {Stationextension: 1000, id: 2, name: cindy}
        ]
```

My pseudo code is this.

```
Delete list2[d] (whole dictionary from list of dicts) where list1[d]['extension'] == list2[d]['Stationextension'] AND id == id.
```

List 1 is much smaller and has to stay unchanged relative to list 2 if that matters.

Using Python3.3, I have something like

```
[x for x in list2 if (list1[x]['stationExtension'] == x.get('extension'))]
```

Thanks !

Comment: just a clarification, given the constraints, in this case, wont all the items get deleted? @AlexKliorin anyway, check my answer

Comment: Is there a reason these are lists, rather than dicts keyed off the appropriate thing (`(extension, id)` and `(Stationextention, id)` tuples, it looks like)? Because that would make your code a lot simpler, and more efficient to boot.

Comment: Also, it would really help if you gave real data, with the quotes and commas and other things in place, so we can actually test this.

Comment: Finally, are you asking how to do the equivalent of your Python 3.3 code in 2.7? Because if so… the exact same code does the exact same thing in 2.7. It doesn't work in 3.3, and it doesn't work in the same way in 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list2 = [x for x in list2 if {'extension': x['Stationextension'], 'id': x['id']} not in list1]
```

or, if you know that the lengths and indexes will match:

```
list2 = [y for x,y in itertools.izip(list1, list2) if x['extension'] == y['StationExtension'] and x['id'] == y['id']]
```

Comment: I'm constantly amazed by the level of knowledge the users of this site have. This worked perfectly. I gotta brush up on my list comprehension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to use the right data structures for the job. Instead of figuring out how to search a list based on a key, use a dict with that key. For example:

```
dict1 = {x['extension']: x for x in list1}
```

Now, you can just write this:

```
[x for x in list2 if x['stationExtension'] in dict1}
```

---

Elsewhere in your question, it seems like you wanted to use the extension *and* the id, not just the extension, as a key. But that's just as easy; you can use a tuple:

```
dict1 = {(x['extension'], x['id']): x for x in list1}

[x for x in list2 if (x['stationExtension'], x['id']) in dict1}
```

---

If you want to know why your code doesn't work… let's look at it:

```
[x for x in list2 if (list1[x]['stationExtension'] == x.get('extension'))]
```

`list1[x]` is trying to use the dict as an index, which doesn't mean anything. What you really want to say is "if, for any element of list1, `element['stationExtension'] == x.get('extension')`". And you can translate that almost directly to Python:

```
[x for x in list2 
 if any(element['stationExtension'] == x.get('extension')
        for element in list1)]
```

And of course to add the `and element['id'] == x['id']` onto the end of the condition.

But again, the `dict` is a better solution. Besides being a whole lot simpler to read and write, it's also more efficient. Searching for any matches in a list requires checking each element in the list; searching for any matches in a dict just requires hashing the key and looking it up in a hash table. So, this way takes O(NM) time (where N is the length of list1, and M is the length of list2), while the dict only takes O(M) time.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7:

```
removelist=[]
for i,x in enumerate(list2):
    if x['Stationextension'] == list1[i]['extension'] and x['id'] == list1[i]['id']:
        removelist+=[i]
```

And once you've decided what to delete:

```
for x in removelist:
    del list1[x]
```

Comment: And how do you deal with the list changing in size while you iterate on it?

Comment: nice, i didn't think about it earlier, now that i know how to do it, i'll implement it in an edit

Comment: is it okay now @jsbueno

Comment: Using `list2.index(x)` repeatedly means you're searching `list2` over and over again, which is going to be very slow, and incorrect if there are ever duplicates in the list, and very easy to get wrong with a simple typo. If you need the index of `x` in `list2`, just use `for i, x in enumerate(list2)`.

Comment: And by the same token, `list2.remove(x)` will have the exact same problems—slow, incorrect if there are duplicates, easy to screw up. Just stash the indices, then you can delete all of them by, e.g., iterating in reverse order.

Comment: You are assuming list1 to contain items that are teh same as the items in list2 - (thus `list2.index(x)` would find something) - that is not the case in teh example above as well. (Again., th O.P. does not give a lot of info)

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi: The new version still doesn't work, for two reasons. First, you're assuming `list1` and `list2` have matching values at the same position—which is true in his example, but according to his description isn't generally true. Second, your `for` loop will delete the wrong elements. Imagine that your `removeList` is `(0, 2)`. First you `del list1[0]`, which shifts everything down. Then you `del list[2]`, which deletes the current element 2—but you wanted to delete the _original_ element 2, which is now element 1. If you want to do things this way, you need to iterate backward.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to delete items from list2 with the same value in "Stationextention" on list2 and "extention" on list 1 - 
You better first create a set with all values to delete - that will avoid a linear search at each time you want to check if an entry will stay:

```
indexes = set(item["extention"] for item in list1)
```

And - one thing that happens is that you usually can't iterate over a list and delete items from it while at it:

```
new_list2 = []
for item in list2:
    if item["Stationextention"] not in indexes: 
         new_list2.append(item)

list2 = new_list2
```